# Issue using solr and rspec

Tags: rspec, autocomplete, sunspot-rails

I have a method which prompts auto complete. I am using Solr for the same.

The method in the controller looks like:

```
def address_autocomplete
    search = Sunspot.search(Address) do
      fulltext params[:term]
      with(:user_id, current_user.id)
    end.results
    render json: search.map(&:address_with_id_to_string).to_json
  end
```

I am writing rspec for the above method. The test for the above method is as shown below:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AddressesController, type: :controller do
  describe Address, search: true do
    describe 'Search' do
      before(:each) do
        Sunspot.remove_all!
        Sunspot.commit
      end

      let!(:address) do
        create(:address,
               name: 'Michael Jackson',
               street: '100 spear st',
               postal_code: '94105',
               state_or_region: 'California',
               phone_number: '123-456-7890',
               city: 'San Francisco',
               user: user).tap { |b| b.index! }
      end

      describe 'GET #address_autocomplete' do
        let!(:user)  { create :user }
        it 'It prompts autocomplete of addresses' do
          xhr :get, address_autocomplete_addresses_path , term: 'Mic'
          debugger
          ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body).to eq(address.address_with_id_to_string)
          //Check response is desired string or not
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the above code, after debugging I found that Sunspot is unable to return the desired response in search array. The search array is blank. I am unable to find the reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with solr. I was writing the test in integration test folder. This created lot of issues for me. As device helpers are not found in the integration test folder, due to this reason I could not use `sign_in user` as well. I moved my test to unit test and now it works fine.